# How do I create a function and add headers to it using Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Can someone please show me exactly how to define a function to output these values with a header at the top of each column?

Here's what I have so far:

```
function x = myfunct(R,I)

  v=I.*R;

  p=v.*I;

  x=([I', v', p']);

end
```

For example, I want to input:

```
R=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
I=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
```

and have columns such as this with a header on each one.

```
 5.0000    1.0700    5.3500   
 4.0000    1.3300    5.3200    
10.0000    1.3300   13.3000   
 6.0000    0.2600    1.5600    
12.0000    0.5600    6.7200    
 7.0000   -0.3000   -2.1000    
 4.0000   -0.3000   -1.2000
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: The easiest solution involves `table`.

Comment: I've been looking at that under Matlab topics but haven't been able to figure it out. I keep getting errors :(

Answer (score 1):

I would go for an [array2table](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/array2table.html) call in this case, without forgetting to specify the `VariableNames` parameter (a cell array of character vectors in which each "string" represents the name of a column header).

```
function x = myfunct(R,I)
    v = I.*R;
    p = v.*I;
    x = array2table([I', v', p'],'VariableNames',{'A' 'B' 'C'});
end
```

The result is returned in the form of a [table](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html) object, and it seems it's exactly what you are looking for. Here is an example:

```
A    B      C 
_    __    ___

1     1      1
2     4      8
3     9     27
4    16     64
5    25    125
6    36    216
7    49    343
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Cris Luengo suggested, you have to use `table`. For your case, try the following lines:

```
% Table needs column vectors (or matrices)
R = R';
I = I';

table(R, I, x);
```

For more examples, take a look at this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html).